# Are questions ever deleted even from original author

Tags: discussion, support

A while back, I asked a question, and it was down-voted as being too opinion based.  I made some minor modifications to it hoping to correct the issue, but was unsuccessful.

A while later, I noticed it wasn't in my "questions" list, but was able to find it using Google and discovered it was deleted.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions:

> Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors,
>   regardless of the author's reputation

Is this still the case, and if so, how do I view questions of mine which were deleted?

Comment: If they're not actually deleted, then we're using the wrong term.   I'd like to reference my question on UX: "When does delete not mean delete?"  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53711/when-does-delete-not-mean-delete

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Deleted questions do not ever show up in your standard questions list, and they never have for normal users. If your question was deleted *recently*, you can find it easily by clicking on the "deleted recent questions" link at the very bottom of your questions list. Otherwise, you will only be able to access and view the question if you still have a direct link to the question.

Comment: I swore I looked for it and it wasn't there, but now I look and it certainly is.  Thank you.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/165773

Comment: @user1032531 A moderator probably restored it and then re-deleted it (probably animuson)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can see them in your [recently deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1032531). They will be gone in some time, so if you want to keep them, you have to make a backup for yourself.

Comment: The questions will not be gone, they will just not be linked on the recently deleted questions page. Deleted questions are always visible to the author if they bookmarked the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a deleted question that is not recent, you can email

```
team@stackoverflow.com
```

However I would use this sparingly, I am not sure how much trouble it is for them to do this.

Comment: It may be better to ask a site moderator, who are able to see a user's deleted posts.  Even then, some may not want to do it frequently, but it is still better than contacting SE directly.